# Can someone help me work out the kinks in my program?

Tags: java, user-interface

I have to write a calculator program using the Gui components. I have written the program but I'm having issues with my CE button. It is giving me errors. I'm also getting and error in my for loop where I add the operand labels to the expression. I was just hoping to get some help in fixing these errors. Thank you! Please ignore the comments. They are there for my to keep track of what I have to do.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Calculator
{
JFrame window;
// stuff for top panel
JPanel topPanel;
JTextField expr,result;
JButton equals;

// stuff for bottom panel

JPanel bottomPanel,digitsPanel,opsPanel;
JButton[] digits,ops;
JButton clear, clearEntry;
Container content;
Listener listener;
String[] oplabels = { "+", "-", "/", "*" };

public Calculator()
{
    listener = new Listener(); // our Listener class implements ActionListener
    window= new JFrame("GUI Calc");
    content=window.getContentPane();
    content.setLayout( new GridLayout(2,1) );
    topPanel=new JPanel();
    topPanel.setLayout( new GridLayout(1,3) );

    // TOP PANEL WORK

    expr = new JTextField( );
    equals = new JButton("=");
    equals.addActionListener( listener );
    result = new JTextField( );

    topPanel.add( expr );
    topPanel.add( equals );
    topPanel.add( result );

    // BOTTOM PANEL WORK

    bottomPanel = new JPanel();
    bottomPanel.setLayout( new GridLayout(1,2) );

    digitsPanel = new JPanel();
    digitsPanel.setLayout( new GridLayout(4,3) );

    opsPanel = new JPanel();
    opsPanel.setLayout( new GridLayout(4,1) );

    digits  = new JButton[12];
    ops = new JButton[4];

    for (int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)
    {
        digits[i] = new JButton( i+"" );
        digits[i].addActionListener(listener);
        digitsPanel.add( digits[i] );
    }

    clear = new JButton( "C" );
    clearEntry = new JButton( "CE" );
    clear.addActionListener(listener);
    clearEntry.addActionListener(listener);
    digitsPanel.add( clear );
    digitsPanel.add( clearEntry);


    for (int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
    {
        ops[i] = new JButton( oplabels[i] ) ;
        ops[i].addActionListener(listener);
        opsPanel.add( ops[i] );
    }

    bottomPanel.add( digitsPanel );
    bottomPanel.add( opsPanel );


    content.add( topPanel);
    content.add( bottomPanel);

    window.setVisible(true);
}
class Listener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Component clicked = (Component) e.getSource();
        if ( clicked == equals )
        {
            result.setText( evaluate( expr.getText() ) );
            return;
        }
        for ( int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)
        {
            if ( clicked == digits[i] )
            {
                expr.setText( expr.getText() + i );
                return;
            }
        }
        if ( clicked == clear )
        {
            expr.setText("0");
            return;
            // do something

        }
        for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (clicked == digits[i])
            {
            int lastValue = i;
            return;
            }
        }
            if ( clicked == clearEntry )
            {
                expr.setText(expr.getText() - lastValue);
                return;
                // do something
            }

        for ( int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++ )
        {
            if(clicked == oplabels[i])
            {
            expr.setText(expr.getText + oplabels[i]);
            return;
            }
            // tack on that operator to the expr string
        }

    }
    String evaluate( String exp )
    {
        return "NOT WRITTEN YET";
    }
}
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    new Calculator();
}
}
```

Comment: You may want to give people the actual errors that you are seeing and under what conditions.  The more information you give, the more likely somebody can help.

Comment: Calculator.java:121: error: cannot find symbol 
   expr.setText(expr.getText() - lastValue);
  symbol:   variable lastValue
  location: class Calculator.Listener
Calculator.java:128: error: incomparable types: Component and String
                                if(clicked == oplabels[i])
                                           ^
Calculator.java:130: error: cannot find symbol
                                expr.setText(expr.getText + oplabels[i]);
                                                 ^
  symbol:   variable getText
  location: variable expr of type JTextField
3 errors

Comment: Ahhh, so your program isn't giving you errors, the java compiler is, and it's telling you exactly what is wrong... You might want to point out which is line 128/130.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem #1

The compiler is complaining about `expr.setText(expr.getText() - lastValue);` because `lastValue` is undefined.

Having a close look at the code, the only place that `lastValue` is defined is within the `for-loop` before the `if` statement`...but the next issues the`return` statement following it's decleration...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (clicked == digits[i]) {
        int lastValue = i;
        return;
    }
}
if (clicked == clearEntry) {
    expr.setText(expr.getText() - lastValue);
    return;
    // do something
}
```

This not only makes the `lastValue` useless, but it's unlikely that the `if` statement would ever be reached...

### Problem #2

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (clicked == oplabels[i]) {
        expr.setText(expr.getText + oplabels[i]);
        return;
    }
    // tack on that operator to the expr string
}
```

`clicked` is defined as `Component clicked = (Component) e.getSource();` and `oplables` are defined as `String[] oplabels = {"+", "-", "/", "*"};`.  `String` and `Component` are not comparable (also, you want `expr.getText()` not `expr.getText`).

I think you want to do something more like...

```
if (clicked instanceof JButton) { 
    JButton btn = (JButton)clicked)
    for (int i = 0; i < oplabels.length; i++) {
        if (oplabels[i].equals(btn.getText()) {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 128: `clicked` is a `Component` and `oplabels[i]` is a `string` - you can't compare them directly.

Line 130: Missing `()` on `getText()` call.